# In a Cocoa Mac Os X Desktop Application, can I configure the project so that files with no extensions can be dragged into the app's icon?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode7.3

In a Cocoa Mac Os X Desktop Application, can I configure the project so that files with no extensions can be dragged into the app's icon ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app identifies which files it handles (which controls what types can be dragged onto it, and for which your app appears in the Open With menu in Finder) via [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html).

In Xcode, you set this in "Document Types" in the "Info" tab for your app target. The root type (i.e., the type you want for all files) is `public.data`. Basically just add a Document Type, set the identifier to `public.data`, and you're good.

Visual aid:

[image: Xcode screenshot showing document type for all files]

Note that this won't cover folders. For that, use `public.folder`.